# Is there a word or phrase with similar meaning to bond yield, but meaning yield on the actual price paid for a bond some time ago?

Tags: fixed-income, bond-yields

This is what I am looking for:
(coupon amount) / (the amount that I actually paid for the bond some time ago)

Comment: I suppose you can call it the "yield at purchase" (or current yield at time of purchase) but I am not aware of a more specific term.

Comment: @nbbo2 For stocks it seems to be called "Yield On Cost". Probably same could be used for bonds.

Answer (score 4):

You are specifically not considering the fair market price of the bond now, but only what you paid for it, and how much coupon/amortization it has paid out so far, no matter when.  This ratio could be termed "realized holding period return". Correspondingly, the change in the market price of the bond could be termed "**un**realized holding period return". Combining them, we get just "holding period return" (not annualized). It is not very common/useful ratio, but googling it finds some hits.  But this is not very standardized terminology, so I would footnote and explain exactly what I mean by it in detail, to make it easier for other people to reproduce my calculation if they wish. E.g., do you divide by the clean price or the full purchase price? Do you include the accrued coupon not yet paid out in realized or in unrealized? Such little details can change the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for "book yield" or "book yield-to-maturity". For a non-par bond, yield-to-maturity includes accretion to par over life, while current yield (i.e., coupon rate / gross price) does not.